# how to select an anchor tag with a specific id inside a ul using css

Tags: html, css

I want to select a specific anchor in a ul so i can manipulate it using css or jQuery. Like in the code below i want to select home only which i have given an id of 'bt1'. How do i select it?

Thank you in anticipation

```
<div id='TopNav'>
<ul>
  <li> <a id='bt1' href=''>Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="html _docs/contact.html">Contact EHC</a></li>
  <li><a href=''>Student Portal</a></li>
  <li><a href=''>Lecturer Portal</a></li>
  <li><a href=''>How To Apply</a></li>
  <li><a href=''>Student Union</a></li>
  <li><a href=''>News</a></li>
  <li><a href=''>Tutorials</a></li>
  <li><a href=''>Log In</a></li>
  <li class='last'><a href=''>Graduation</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Either `ul #bt1` or just simply `#bt1`.

Comment: `ul li #bt1` in this case

Comment: Did you spend any time at all researching this or trying anything? It's very HTML 101.

Comment: @j08691 i did, i made sure i did before asking. Its just that i have never tried to select an anchor inside a list before. I am kind of teaching myself and new to web development. I thought i would need to follow those child/parent rules like #Topnav ul li clearly i was wrong

Comment: Since IDs must be unique, you can always select them by using `#`. So in your case `#bt1`. You don't need to refer to the list at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since IDs should be unique in your document, you can select it directly:

```
$('#bt1')
```

or

```
#bt1{ ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select it using the unique ID. Just call it out in CSS

```
#bt1{

...

}
```

Comment: The only caveat might be if some pages have #bt1 in a different location, and he only wants to manipulate it IF it's inside a list.

Comment: if it is in another location, then he should use a class, and just have this unique id set for this specific instance.